# Image uploaded but not stored

Tags: php, mysql, image-upload

I am trying to store image name along with other data in the database but not being able to. nothing is inserted in the database. but the image is uploaded in the directory when i close the brace  } before db config. but i got call to an undefined function upload() when i close the function brace } after inserting. here is the code:

```
$imagesub = isset( $_FILES['image'] );

if ( $imagesub ) 
{
    $output=upload();
}
return $output;
function upload()
{

    include_once "class.php";

    $uploader = new Uploader( "image" );

    $uploader->saveIn("images");

    $fileUploaded = $uploader->save();



$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root","","learndb");

if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed this is the error: " . $db->connect_error);
}

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO studentrecords (Name, email, Phone, school,dob,father,feereceived,due,image) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

if($stmt)
{
    $stmt->bind_param("ssisssiis",$name,$email,$phone,$school,$dob,$father,$feereceived,$due,$fileUploaded);
        $stmt->execute();
    $out="<center>information entered.</center>";
        echo "$out";
}
else
{

    $out="DATABASE ERROR!!!";
    echo "$out";
}
      return $out;
}
```

Here is the function save()

```
public function save(){
    $folderIsWriteAble = is_writable( $this->destination );
    if( $folderIsWriteAble ){
        $name = "$this->destination/$this->filename";
        if($succes = move_uploaded_file( $this->fileData, $name ))
        {
            return $name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do the `$uploader->save();` returns the file name?  can you add what's inside the function?

Comment: @roullie i have added it.

Comment: Do you get `DATABASE ERROR!!!`? Have you checked for errors on the bind and/or execute?

Comment: @chris85 I don't get that error. i receive a white blank new page.

Comment: Okay, what do you have in the PHP error logs?

Comment: @chris85 i got call to  undefined function upload()

Answer (score 0):

@Micky you have only 9 fields defined in your insert query but you are passing 10 parameters in ´bind_param()`.

`$stmt->bind_param("ssisssiis",$name,$email,$phone,$school,$dob,$father,$feereceived,$due,$fileUploaded);`

should be

`$stmt->bind_param($name,$email,$phone,$school,$dob,$father,$feereceived,$due,$fileUploaded);`

If it doesn’t resolve your problem then var_dump your $fileUploaded variable and make sure you have compatible datatype defined for column used for storing file name.

Comment: i am passing 9 parameters.

Comment: What about the datatype of $fileUploaded variable and DB field?

Comment: it is blob type and image column.

Comment: Are you able to insert the same output name (value of "$fileUploaded") directly in the DB column?